# Why ubuntu 16.04 can not input Chinese characters using sogou-pinyin input method?

Tags: ubuntu, input, character, fcitx

I wanted to use sogou pinyin input method in my ubuntu 16.04, I followed [this guide](http://pinyin.sogou.com/linux/help.php) and installed it successfully.However, when I wanted to use it, I get the result like this:

[image]

I really can not solve it, is there anyone can help?

What is more, I configured my input method like this:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Give a try for this,

```
$mv ~/.config/SogouPY  ~/SogouPY  
$rm -rf ~/.config/SogouPY
```

The commands just remove the configuration on Sogou.
If it doesn't work try to move it back.

I have similar problem after upgrading system today (Mar 25, 2017). 
I tried to remove fcitx and sogoupinyin, and reinstall it, the problem still remain until I removed the config files.

After removing the config files, try to switch to sogoupinin with `ctrl + space` if you set. if it doesn't work, you may need to restart/log out your system.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to make a supplement on how to use Sogou pinyin on **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS**.

(And I have answered this question on [Sogou Linux forum](http://pinyin.sogou.com/bbs/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=2743669&extra=page%3D1), you can check Chinese version there.)

Sogou pinyin works on Ubuntu 18.04 but something will be wrong after updating.

1. Make mental preparation to reboot many times.
2. Go https://github.com/laomocode/fcitx-sogouimebs/releases and download `sogouimebs.deb` at the bottom of the page.
3. `sudo dpkg -i sogouimebs.deb`
4. Change ibus to fcitx, follow [this page](https://leimao.github.io/blog/Ubuntu-Gaming-Chinese-Input/) to finish the configuration. (Although this page tells you to install google pinyin, you don't have to. We already installed sogou pinyin. And if fcitx icon doesn't show up on your top bar after rebooting, I suggest you just switch between ibus and fcitx several times, and reboot everytime.)
5. Click fcitx icon --> configure (If you don't know how to configure, [the page](https://blog.csdn.net/win_turn/article/details/53637293) may help.)

If it doesn't work, google pinyin is really a good substitute, which I am using. I did take some time how to set up Sogou on Ubuntu 20.04, but this Sogou doesn't support use English punctuation while inputting Chinese. Google pinyin support this well.

BTW, if you really want to know how to use English punctuation while inputting Chinese in Sogou, I also found an interesting way, however easy to stuck:

Close internal Chinese-English switch in Sogou, and set `left shift` to another  English input, so it feels like you still in Sogou and half-width punctuation will not be affected.

---

I haven't try this method on Ubuntu 16.04, but I think it will be much more easier if you are using that version.

1. Download the official package [here](https://pinyin.sogou.com/linux/?r=pinyin).
2. [Configure fcitx](https://leimao.github.io/blog/Ubuntu-Gaming-Chinese-Input/).

This should be working as the official page says they support this version.
[sogou pinyin Linux page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeJwG.png)

Comment: The question was about Ubuntu 16.04. Can you confirm that your proposed method also works in this version?

Comment: I have just updated this answer. Thank you for refining.@wychmaster

Answer (score 1):

This is worked !

```
$mv ~/.config/SogouPY  ~/SogouPY  
$rm -rf ~/.config/SogouPY
```